# Getting error about an undefined reference, even though it is defined

Tags: c++, header, header-files

```
   //Double.h file
   #ifndef Double_h
   #define Double_h

   int add(int x,int y);

   #endif 


  //Double.cpp file
  int add(int x,int y)
 {
    return x + y;
 }

 //main.cpp file
 #include <iostream>
 #include "Double.h"
 using namespace std;


 int main()
  {
    cout << add(7,8)<<endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

It's supposed to be a simple 7+8 program and I'm using Codeblocks for C++. It keeps saying that `add wasn't declared in this scope`.And when I DID declare `int add (int x,int y)` in the main.cpp file after `using namespace std;`, it said `"undefined reference for add(int,int)`. I don't understand this and I really thought it was going to work. Can someone please point out the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your header file `Double.h` is in the proper folder when you are compiling `main.cpp` (are they by chance duplicated and your main.cpp is seeing a wrong file ?).

Your `Double.cpp` also should include `Double.h`. Also make sure you compile both `main.cpp` and `double.cpp` together for generating final executable output file.

This program should work.

Comment: it still doesnt work.they re all in the same folder..this is really odd.

Comment: and wait what do you mean by compiling both main.cpp and double.cpp together??Build both of them right???I tried and it keeps saying about some "undefined reference Winmain@16"error

Comment: I have mentioned in the answer that `#include"Double.h"` in `Double.cpp` (not .h). However, if everything is in the same folder it should compile. I am not sure (possible that some typing error in your code).

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you include "Double.cpp" as well in you main.cpp?

Answer (score -1):

move the declaration

```
int add(int x, int y);
```

out of the `#ifndef` block